# How do I thicken my procedural dot texture?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, node-editor, procedural

I have this procedural noisy dots texture and I would like to thicken the dots outward.

[image]

I am looking to create an effect where the dots would expand similar to how you can grow a selection in GIMP or photoshop and then fill the selection with black.
[image]

This is the desired effect. Thanks for any help.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

What kind of dots are you making? If a "swiss cheese" effect would suit you, a Voronoi texture works quite well. If you like, you can use a Power (math) node to control the size of the dots.

[image: swiss-cheese-nodes]
[image: swiss-cheese]

Comment: Why power instead of multiply?

Comment: @GiantCowFilms Multiply will brighten/darken everything. Power will make bright values brighter and dark values darker.